# Density and expected value of a continuous distribution function

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

\begin{equation*}
F(x)=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{lr}
0,&y<0\\
\frac{y(y+1)}{110},&0\leq y\leq 10\\
1,&y>10
\end{array}   \right.
\end{equation*}

There are five individual runs of the experiment. Let $M$ denote the maximum result for the five runs. Determine $P(M\leq m)$.

I wrote: $P(Y_1 \leq m \cap Y_2 \leq m \cap \dots \cap Y_5 \leq m)$.

I think that's correct. I'm unsure how to get $g(m)$. Is not the density of $m$ the derivative of $G(m)$? How do you take a derivative of a string of intersections?

I was told that it's actually the integral of $G(m)$. But in my notes, it says that to get $F$ from $f$, you take the integral. In this example, since I want $g(m)$ from $G(m)$, it seems the derivative is in order.

I'm confused. Please help.

Comment: The first sentence should read "when 10<y." Why it won't show up is beyond me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$P(Y\leq y)=F(y) = \begin{cases} 0, \text{if}\ y<0 \\ y(y+1)/110, \text{if}\  0 \leq y  \leq 10 \\ 1, \text{if y > 10}\end{cases}$

This is a cumulative distribution function (cdf). You have 5 (independently) runs. You are right that

$P(max\{Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4,Y_5\}\leq m)=P(Y_1\leq m\cap Y_2\leq m\cap Y_3\leq m\cap Y_4\cap Y_5\leq m)$

Since the variables are independent it is equal to

$P(Y_1\leq m)\cdot P(Y_2\leq m)\cdot P(Y_3\leq m)\cdot P(Y_4\leq m)\cdot P(Y_5\leq m)$

**update**

To get the pdf differentiate $\left(\frac{m(m+1)}{110}\right)^5$ w.r.t $m$.

Comment: So,it's (y(y+1)/110)^5 d/dy?

Comment: Therie is no need to differentiate. And you have to input m for y, because m=y

Comment: My professor told me to differentiate the product.

Comment: But you want to calculate $P(Y_1\leq m)$ for instance. Here you need clearly the cdf, not pdf.

Comment: You're confusing me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48094/discussion-between-t-1000s-son-and-callculus).

Comment: @T-1000'sSon I´ve made an update.

Comment: A reply would be nice.